# Display message on jquery slide login form

Tags: javascript, php, html

Wasnt too sure what title to put for this but here goes.

Originally I made a seperate login page for members to be able to access different areas of a site to standard users. 
I later updated my site to use a jquery slide form that is accessible from all pages of the site by clicking on a tab at the top of the screen.
My problem is, I want to be able to display statuses on this sliding form to show when login failed.

My original login.php redirected the user to the seperate memberlogin.php page using:

```
header('Location: memberlogin.php?status=1'); //No such user
header('Location: memberlogin.php?status=2'); //Incorrect password
```

I no longet have this memberlogin page instead have a loginform.php that is included on each of the webpages.

I now need to redirect the user to the page they were on\are on at the time of logging in and also make sure the sliding form is in the open position with a message displayed on it when the login fails.
Each of my pages stores the name of the page that is selected for CSS purposes so I thought I could use this to redirect:

```
header("Location:$thisPage");
```

however this just loads the index.php page each time. I also cant work out how to open the slider without clicking on the tab. The javascript that runs for it when clicked is:

```
// Expand Panel
$("#open").click(function(){
    $("div#panel").slideDown("slow");

});
```

so in my login.php which is called by the loginform i tried putting:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">$("div#panel").slideDown("slow");</script>';
```

This also doesnt work. Appologies im new to both javascript and php

Comment: You need to make sure your element #panel was loaded before you call script because the script is build once time.

Comment: @hicurin it probably isnt then. I dont have any sort of debugging software on my machine at work to test it. Do you think I should create some sort of variable instead. For instance set a variable called login_failed and include a php file on each of the webpages to check for this after the login form include? This might solve the issue with getting the slider to be open but how can I ensure the user get re-directed to the page they were on at the time?

Comment: Please try it again without div tag, like this: echo '<script type="text/javascript">$("#panel").slideDown("slow");</script>';

Comment: @hicurin No, doesnt work

Comment: What is the defenition of $thisPage?

Comment: <script>
  $(document).ready(
    function (){
      $("div#panel").slideDown("slow");
    }
  );
</script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

And:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(
    function (){
      $("div#panel").slideDown("slow");
    }
  );
</script>
```

The cause is that you realy need to be sure that #panel element was loaded. Thats why you should use .ready() event. It is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready

Comment: the HTTP_REFERER works a treat the slideDown function however im still having problems with. Without some sort of debugger on this machine though I cant follow the process. I think I will have to take the work home and try to test it from there (cant install anything on these machines).

Comment: Just looked again at my code. I had placed the 2 include files (one for the header of the page and the other which was the login form) in the <body> of the page. The check to see if a user is logged on before allowing them to view this page is located at the very top meaning the slideDown function was placed before the included login form. After shuffling these around the form now slides open. Thanks for your help